# Move a seam application to OSGI

Tags: jboss, osgi, seam

i' ve some web applications developed using Seam Framework 2.3 + jBoss AS 7 + Hybernate.

Since i' ve been studying OSGI for a while, i was wondering if is possible to move my applications to the osgi world for modularizing everything; i' ve read a lot of blogs and these interesting discussions as well ([how-to-modularize-an-enterprise-application-with-osgi-and-ee6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284491/how-to-modularize-an-enterprise-application-with-osgi-and-ee6/) and [how-to-modularize-a-jsf-facelets-spring-application-with-osgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575669/how-to-modularize-a-jsf-facelets-spring-application-with-osgi)) but honestly i still don't really know where i should start from, since i' ve never used OSGI before.

According to you

1. Is it possible (and useful) do such things?
2. According to your experience, what would be a good starting point?

Thanks for help

Comment: OK, let' s try again..my question is either too stupid or too vague, maybe both :)..i don' t wanna have a step-by-step guide, i'd like to know if some of you has ever tried to do what i' m trying to do, or unfortunately i' m the first crazy one..i found some documentation about eclipse equinox but i still don' t know how i should start..theoretically i should simply separate every functionality provided by my application in an OSGI service, keeping implementation and interface separated(?)..and concerning my xhtml pages, maybe i should treat them with servlet bridge, or something like that (?)

Comment: But what about putting everything together and deploy using AS JBoss 7? Any hint? Am i trying to do something impossible or just useless? thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

**Approach**

Possibly start with a toy application as a spike, a WAB (OSGi WAR) and single service bundle.

Definitely take an iterative approach.  As far as I know JBoss supports the mixing of OSGi services and Java EE stuff, via JBoss modules/msc, this will allow you to try OSGi and migrate gradually.

I think you'll find some things are incredibly easy and others very hard, so pick easy battles while you're getting familiar.  In the end you may stick with a hybrid approach.

**Build**

What's your build tool?  Mostly like Maven or Ant, in which case have a look at [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html)
or [bnd](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Ant) respectively.  You'll need to ensure the OSGi metadata is present in each of your bundles (Bundle-SymbolicName, Import-Package, Export-Package, etc).  If you're using Maven see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10436865/best-way-to-convert-existing-java-projects-to-osgi-bundles/10438035#10438035).

It can be tricky to divide a monolithic app into modules, but as a general rule when you migrate a reasonable sized module you should have separate bundles for API and implementation (which is good design anyway but has implications for the runtime too).

**Interop**

You can acquire OSGi services, access bundles etc using the low level framework APIs from an injected `BundleContext`, which will give you a low-level programmatic hook into OSGi.  It should be as simple as:

```
@Resource
BundleContext context;
```

Unless your Java EE code is packaged as JBoss modules I don't think it will be easy for you to call the other way (e.g. OSGi service looking up Java EE service) without resorting to something like JNDI.

You should be able to install the webconsole and see what Java EE bits are registered in OSGi, and similarly check JNDI to see what's available OSGi for Java EE.

**Migrating Services**

While OSGi is a lot of fun, using the raw framework API results in quite a bit of boilerplate code and it's unlikely you'll need the power or want the coupling.  You can use a number of dependency injection frameworks on top of OSGi; blueprint (Spring-like), Peaberry (Guice) and Declarative Services for example.

I'm biased but Declarative Services has a strong affinity to the OSGi µservice model and the implementations are lightweight.

**CDI**

I don't know much about Seam/CDI, but [Pax CDI](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/PAXCDI/Pax+CDI) might help (though JBoss might already have covered this).

**Web**

Are you planning to have a highly modular UI with hot deploy of the various components?  If not then probably best just to package the UI as a WAB.  A WAB is a skinny WAR (i.e. it imports rather than embeds most dependencies).  Even if you're after a highly modular, dynamic frontend, I would definitely do this for the first pass.

**JPA**

A word of warning - JPA implementations typically don't play well in OSGi environments, you may want to look at Apache Aries or Eclipse Gemini.  Another option might be to leave the JPA stuff in Java EE space and access Java EE DAOs/Repositories as OSGi services.  Again though you may experience some classloading issues.

Possibly useful examples https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBOSGI/Provided+Examples

Comment: If you're using, or are experienced with Spring, then Blueprint will be more familiar than Declarative Services.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your reply but unfortunately i' m still a little bit confused..summarizing what you are suggesting to do is: WAB for my view, Gemini/Aries for JPA and PojoSR for everything else? yes, maybe the hybrid approach could be the better way to proceed (at least for now)..i' ll try it out, thank you

Comment: @Danilo, sorry that was an appalling answered - it should have been downvoted for lack of clarity/coherence/relevance =)  Slightly improved version above.

Comment: thanks for your hints..they are more than welcome ;) i' ll give them a try..btw, i would like to keep using Seam 2.3 as framework, and have something like an OSGI layer running underneath (maybe i should have said that :s )..so it' s not a real migration, it' s more an adaptation..i' ve started from JPA stuff trying to use Eclipse Gemini (but it seems that it doesn' t support hibernate) i' ll let you know how it goes, thanks for helping

Comment: @Danilo - An adaption rather than 100% migration is certainly going to be less painful.  You might even be able to leave the JPA stuff on the EE side and invoke DAOs etc from the OSGi side.

Comment: (BTW you can vote answers up if they help and accept them if they _solve_ your problem)

Comment: yeah, i know..unfortunately i cannot vote you up because i don' t have enough reputation :(..and since my problem is not solved, i cannot accept your answer as the correct one (even if is a good starting point indeed)..but i for sure will in case of success :) thanks again