# Create a Web Service in JBoss AS 7 OSGi container

Tags: web-services, osgi, jboss7.x

I'm fairly new to OSGi (and JBoss), so forgive me if I've missed something in the documentation - I've been searching for a day or so now.

I'm trying to create a web service hosted within the JBoss OSGi container.  The goal is to be able to hit `http://localhost:8080/getStuff` and receive a JSON object.  Is this possible within OSGi?  If so, is this possible within JBoss7's OSGi container?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely possible - I'd suspect you'll find better results by googling "OSGi webservice example" than if you include "JBoss ...", also search for implementation examples ([Jersey](http://jersey.java.net), [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), etc).

You can create a WAB which is essientally just a WAR with OSGi metadata, that imports dependencies rather than embed them in WEB-INF/lib.  JBoss uses [PaxWeb](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web) to provide WAB/WAR support (it wraps an instance of Jetty).

Projects like [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net) and [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) state that they work on OSGi, so apart from your services, from the webcontainer's perspect it's the same as webservices in a Java EE environment.

JBoss specific examples: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBOSGI/Provided+Examples (didn't see WS examples though).

Comment: @Ledivin, I commented on another question covering OSGi in JBoss 7, no webservices but might be of some use to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130553/move-a-seam-application-to-osgi/15248556#15248556 HTH